# Make an AJAX call to load JSON data to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to load JSON data to sessionStorage which I can retrieve later, but can't figure it out! I think I'm doing it all wrong.
Should the Ajax call be made from a different script? Is it okay to put it inside the storeUser function?

```
function StoreUser() {
    let user = {
        'id' : 1 ,
        'fisrtName' : 'Alexander',
        'lastName' : 'Udose',
        'email' : 'XXXXXX@yahoo.com',
        'phoneNumber' : '555555555',
        'address' : '200 CrestView Church RD',
        'creditCard' : '4566XXXXXXXXXX',
        'favoriteFoods' : [
            'Okazi Soup',
            'Egusi Soup',
            'Jollof rice'
        ]
    };

    let person = JSON.stringify(user);

    localStorage.setItem('myPerson', person);

     // XHRrequest 
     let xhr;

     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
         XHR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     };

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
              let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(data);
          }
      };

      XHR.open('POST','person')
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  One problem in the code is XHR.open is case sensitive -- you previously defined xhr.  But 'loading' data to storage may not be the correct term.  Perhaps 'save' data to storage?

Comment: Ajax calls are for client-server communications.  You do not make an Ajax call to load data kept in localStorage.

Comment: What is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: If you *do* need Ajax here (and it's not clear that you do, as @user1532208 says), I would strongly recommend using `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` (let alone falling back to something else if `XMLHttpRequest` somehow doesn't exist in any browser that anyone actually uses). Since your code uses `let` you are clearly only targeting modern browsers anyway (or aiming to transpile down to ES5, in which case using `fetch` again won't be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

You only need these lines to save and load a serialized object using localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('myPerson', person); //Saves person to localStorage
person = localStorage.getItem('myPerson');  //Loads person from localStorage
person = JSON.parse(person); //Converts the string back to an object
```